# Mongoose cannot .insertMany()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, error-handling

I've looked everywhere and I cannot figure out why I get this error while I try to create and save documents with Mongoose.

It has worked to save individual documents with `await fruit.save();`, but when I run the script to add multiple documents with `.insertMany()` I get the following message in terminal and I have no clue what to do with it.

```
/Users/FruitsProjectMongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3519
        
        for (let i = 0; i < error.writeErrors.length; ++i) {
                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at /Users/FruitsProjectMongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3519:47
    at collectionOperationCallback (/Users/FruitsProjectMongoose/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:194:24)
    at /Users/FruitsProjectMongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:349:66
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

It would be an understatement to say that I have tried everything that I could think of/find across the web. I’ve messaged a few devs. and they’ve recommended me to try some things but no luck. I really need some help with this. I start to think it might be something wrong with my system.

I’ve installed MongoDB through Homebrew and Mongoose through npm in the past two days so everything is up-to-date.

The `fruitsDB` exists and I am able to access and view the collections and the individually added documents through the MongoDB shell `mongosh`.

Here is my simple JS script:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);

// Connect to MongoDB by port and catch errors.
main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB')
    .then(() => console.log('Connected!'));


    // Defining a Model Schema.
    const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    const fruitSchema = new Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            require: true
        },
        rating: {
            type: Number,
            require: true
        },
        review: {
            type: String,
            require: true
        }
    });

    const peopleSchema = new Schema({
        name: String,
        age: Number
    });


    // Create a Model.
    const Fruit = new mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);
    const People = new mongoose.model("People", peopleSchema);


    // Create & Save a Document.
    const fruit = new Fruit({
        name: "Banana",
        rating: 10,
        review: "Perfection!"
    });
    // await fruit.save();

    const people = new People({
        name: "Eduard",
        age: 25
    });
    // await people.save();


    // Create & Save docs. in Bulk.
    const kiwi = new Fruit({
        name: "Kiwi",
        rating: 9,
        review: "Great, kinda expensive!"
    });
    
    const orange = new Fruit({
        name: "Orange",
        rating: 6,
        review: "Too sweet."
    });

    const apple = new Fruit({
        name: "Apple",
        rating: 7,
        review: "Great fruit!"
    });

    Fruit.insertMany([kiwi, orange, apple], function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Succesfully saved to fruitsDB");
        }
    });


    mongoose.connection.close();
};
```

MongoDB server is running on `brew services start mongodb-community`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've missed a set of curly braces. So the correct syntax is this.

```
    await Fruit.insertMany([kiwi, orange, apple], {function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Succesfully saved to fruitsDB");
        }
    }});
```